# bash do something on a specific user login

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to execute a certain bash script when a certain user logs in.
I thought of calling the script in the initialization file of that user e.g. `.bashrc`, but this is not applicable, as in real life others shouldn't be allowed to write in users initialization files.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve it using the comman `finger` in an infinite loop and when the lines output of the command increase that means that someone logged in and then I can handle that by doing whatever I want with this user, here is the code:

```
#! /bin/bash
n=0;
while(true)
do
    if [ $n -gt `finger | awk 'END{print NR}'` ]
    then
        mailx -s "hey you" `awk  'END{print $1}'` < mailBody
    fi 
    n=`finger | awk 'END{print NR}'`;   
done
```

Note: you can initialize `n` with `n=${finger | awk 'END{print NR}'}` to avoid considering that someone logged in at the beginning of script execution,or whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

Make user's .bashrc owned by root and have 644 permissions. Make it look as follows:

```
run_specific_command_that_the_user_cannot_bypass
[ -r ~/.bashrc.user] && . ~/.bashrc.user
```

Or use system-wide /etc/profile (or whatever it is called on your box). There is no other option.

Comment: I said I don't wanna it through `.bashrc`

Comment: you said you don't want it because others would be able to hijack it. I suggested how to do it in a safe way. You can do the same with system-wide /etc/profile. I don't think there's any other choice.

Answer (score 0):

Add a line like this to the tail of `/etc/bash.bashrc` or `/etc/profile`:

```
if [ $USER == 'jsmith' ]; then do-something-interesting; fi
```

Comment: again.. I wan't it away from editing initialization files.. any way??